DB2 connection for a AS400 in powerapps
I want to connect powerapps to a AS400.
I have installed On-premises data gateway.
As far as I have studied, there is only a DB2 connector in powerapps, but I can not connect to the server, because I think it is not possible to connect with DB2 connector to a AS400?
I get this error, when using port 50000:
Microsoft Db2 Client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:50000 SQLSTATE=08S01 SQLCODE=-1037
(please note, that I am not the owner of the AS400, but I have access rights for using it as a DMS).
Can I do this maybe via a Azure Data Factory or something else?
Tried to connect with the DB2 Connector.

It looks like the connector is attempting to connect to port 50000.  Are you able to change it to connect to port 446?

@jweberhard: I now get Microsoft Db2 Client: The host resource could not be found. Check that the Initial Catalog value matches the host resource name. SQLSTATE=HY000 SQLCODE=-360      inner exception: Microsoft Db2 Client: The host resource could not be found. Check that the Initial Catalog value matches the host resource name. SQLSTATE=HY000 SQLCODE=-360 clientRequestId: b5441293-6315-4c11-9ff5-aec3ddd60bf6

From the documentation, It appears that use of the DB2 connector requires a gateway to be set up (it also appears to be a premium service for Power Apps which might mean you need the spend $$$ command) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/db2/#default

My only guess is the the connector requires the RDB or database name to be specified if the RDB name does not match the system name.   On the IBM i, use the command WRKRDBDIRE.  Find the entry where the remote location is *LOCAL.  Then configure the connector to use that RDB/database name.
